# Passing POST value from VIEW to CONTROLLER to MODEL in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Ok I stripped out validation and other code to make this example as transparent as possible. I am unable to `POST` a VAR to my MODEL.

## VIEW

```
<?php echo form_open('invoice'); ?>
  <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
  <?php echo form_input('order_num', $this->input->post('order_num')); ?>
  <?php echo form_submit('submit','submit'); ?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

## CONTROLLER

```
public function invoice()
  {
  $order = $this->input->post('order_num');
  $this->General_Model->get_customer_order($order);
  }
```

## MODEL

```
function get_customer_order($order)
  {
    . . .
  $this->db->where('client_orders.id', $order);
  $result = $this->db->get('client_orders');
    . . .

  }
```

Ok Basically you enter an order number on the form. Then it goes to the controller which does the validation (i removed it here to keep example simple) and finally it passes the data to the model which runs the query on the db and returns the `$result`.

However instead of my desired output im getting: Fatal error: Call to a member function get_customer_order() on a non-object  **and**  A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined property: Account_dashboard::$General_Model

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does `$this->input->post('order_num')` per chance type check to `FALSE`? (e.g. `if ($this->input->post('order_num') === FALSE)`) ? You said you stripped out validation to make this simple, but that might be where your issue is.

Comment: @TimPost No it doesn't and for the sake of my sanity i tried running the form without any validation at all like the example i gave above and im still getting the same error :/

Comment: Can you post the first few lines of the Model (up to the constructor if it has one) and the code you're using in your controller to load it?

Comment: Yup, stripping out the code to make the example transparent appears to have stripped out the problem code. There is nothing wrong with what you've posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're loading the model in your controller:

```
$this->load->model('General_Model');
```

The controller line should

```
$data['order'] = $this->General_Model->get_customer_order($order);
```

Then you pass $data to the view.

Comment: yes i am loading it.. Thats not the issue here.. This is really racking my brain..

Comment: He is getting a "call to member function on a non-object"

Comment: Something isn't working there, it's trying to read General_Model as a string and not a model, where are you loading the model?

Comment: @RickCalder Yeah, I see now (I think he edited the post within the grace period), or I just didn't notice it before.

Comment: @Rick ok at rick my mistake i was loading '$this->load->model('General_model');' Which was causing the above error, I didn't realize the 'm' was lowercase --> however now im getting `$order` is undefined

Comment: which one is returning that error, the controller or the model? because that isn't making sense, that code looks fine for what you're trying to do.

Comment: The model is getting the post because I put this in the model and it was working but it isn't returning the result to the view.  'echo $order; echo 'hello model'; exit(); '

Comment: I just got it working. Actually that wasn't reason why. I had two errors 1 I was passing to the function name wrong `get_customer_orders` [s] and was calling `General_model` instead of `General_Model` in the $data['return'] -- I didn't know it was case sensitive I only thought the first letter needed to capitalized. Thanks for your help again!. :)

Comment: My pleasure, glad you got it sorted!